# Show a continuous function whose limits are finite is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

$f : (0, +∞) → \mathbb R$ is continuous. $\lim_{x→0+} f(x)<\infty$ and $\lim_{x→+∞} f(x)<\infty$ . Show $f$ is bounded on its domain.

My idea:

1. Try to modify $(0, +∞)$ to be a compact set. Stuck here.

OR

2. Show by contradiction that there is $a$ such that $f(a)=+\infty$. I guess I should use continuity to show contradiction with the limits. Stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f=l  $(say) so given $\epsilon>o \exists G>0 $ such that $x>G \implies l-\epsilon<f(x)<l+\epsilon$ So $f$ is bounded on $(G,\infty)$

Since $lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f=m  $(say)so given $\epsilon>o \exists \delta>0 $ such that $0<x<\delta  \implies m-\epsilon<f(x)<m+\epsilon$. So $f$ is bounded on $(0,\delta)$

Now $f$ is continuous on $[\delta ,G]\implies f$ is uniformly continuous  on $[\delta ,G]$ and  hence bounded  there.

Thus $f$ bounded on its domain

Comment: Could you explain how we get uniformly continuous from continuous?

Comment: Every continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous on $[\delta,G]$